# A technical question about a paper by Gross-Hacking-Keel

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, cluster-algebras

I have a technical question on the commutativity of diagrams (2.11) and (2.12) in the paper ["Birational geometry of cluster algebras"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2573) by Gross-Hacking-Keel:

For the leftmost square in (2.11), if I follow
$$\mathbb{k}[M^\circ]\overset{\mu_k^* }{\rightarrow} \mathbb{k}[M^\circ]\rightarrow \mathbb{k}[(K^\circ)^*],$$

then by (2.6),
for any $z^m$ in the source, $\mu_k^* (z^m)=z^m(1+z^{v_k})^{-\langle d_ke_k, m\rangle}$, whose image in $\mathbb{k}[(K^\circ)^* ]$ should be $z^m 2^{-\langle d_k e_k, m\rangle}$. This is because by definition, $K^\circ=K\cap N^\circ$ consists of elements $n\in N^\circ$ such that {$n,N_{uf}\cap N^\circ$}=0 (this is from Remark 2.2). Since $v_k=${$e_k,-$} is $0$ on $K^\circ$ (for $d_ke_k\in N_{uf}\cap N^\circ$, and $d_k>0$), $z^{v_k}=1\in \mathbb{k}[(K^\circ)^* ]$. But the commutativity of the diagram means the image of $z^m$ is $z^m$, which seems to assert that $z^{v_k}=0$ in $\mathbb{k}[(K^\circ)^*]$. Do I miss anyting?

There is a similar issue with the left square of (2.12).

Any comment is appreciated.